# Support with ISBLANK and IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm looking to return a value based on the latest of a range of cells having a result.

I log data at fixed points and want to be able to display the latest value listed. I've tried using If and ISBLANK but don't seem to be able to find the best combination that works.

Currently looking at this set up:

Display latest grade in K3. Information should be taken from cells S3, W3 and AA3 in that order. Ie. If there is data in S3 only then display that result in K3. If there is data in W3 then display the data from W3 in K3, and if there is data in AA3 then display that data in K3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean: `=IF(S3<>"",S3,IF(W3<>"",W3,IF(AA3<>"",AA3,"")))` in `K3`? Also, what if there is data in `S3` and `AA3` only. Would that be possible?

Comment: Or even `=IF(S3,S3,IF(W3,W3,IF(AA3,AA3,"")))` if your grades are numbers :)

Comment: Even, if you fill them in sequence; you could use: `=CHOOSE(COUNTA(S3,W3,AA3),S3,W3,AA3)`

Comment: JvdV the CHOOSE/COUNTA method was the closest to what I'm after, however if S3 is empty but W3 has a value it doesnt return it.....is there any way to amend this to always pick up the last value for the three cells (ie if AA3 has a value display that, if not then display W3 if that has a value, if not then display S3 if that has a value, if not them display nothing?

Comment: Mark maybe you're looking for this solution: `=IF(AA3<>"",AA3,IF(W3<>"",W3,IF(S3<>"",S3,"")))` P.S. If you want to tag people then you need to use `@` character before typing in their name. Your previous comment won't be seen by JvdV.

Comment: @JustynaMK. Thanks.....That will give me the first piece of data entered in the list rather than the last in the list.

Comment: Mark thanks for the update. I fail to understand why it wouldn't work - see the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/HzRf8X8.png). The formula properly returns "e" as this is the value entered into cell AA3. What else would you expect to see?

Comment: @JustynaMK. Sorry yes it has worked....thank you very much!!

Comment: No problem at all. I'll post an answer so that other users know it has been solved. Feel free to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the commentary section, you can use `=IF(AA3<>"",AA3,IF(W3<>"",W3,IF(S3<>"",S3,"")))` formula. Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(TEXTJOIN(REPT(" ",100),TRUE,AA3,W3,S3),100))
```

Provided that you are using a version that supports TEXTJOIN.  The formula can easily be extended for additional cells if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative without TEXTJOIN.

```
=LOOKUP(REPT("Z",99),CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},"",S2,W2,AA2))
```

Which can be extended for additional cells by extending the inline array {1,2,3,4} and the cell references.  The last cell with data per the order in the formula will be chosen (using binary search method).